# GCP - Create billing account without organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm Project Owner of a few GCP projects, all of which are linked to no Organization in GCP, and are linked to the same billing account.

As a side note, I'm also Editor and Organization Admin of a project under an organization (call it Organization X), but I don't have access to its billing account.

I will soon need to create a new billing account and move the no-organization projects to this new account, but I would like the new account to be without organization.

However, I'm facing a problem: when I go to https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/create, the respective "Create a new billing account" form shows the following fields:

- **Name**
- **Organization**
- **Country**

The problem is that the "Organization" dropdown is required. (It only gives the option of selecting Organization X, and it's greyed out since I don't have access to its billing account). So, it looks like I can't proceed unless I create an organization.

In the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account, there is a portion that says:

> Depending on your configuration, you will also need to select one of the following:
>
> - **Organization**: If you see an **Organization** drop-down, then you must also select an Organization before you can continue.

I can't seem to find any configuration that allows choosing whether this field is required or not. Should I be able to create the billing account without an organization, or will I have to create one to be able to proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your Google Cloud resources using an Organization node, and you are a member of that Google Cloud Organization, then you must be a Billing Account Creator to create a new Cloud Billing account.

Specifically, if you are a Google Cloud user within an Organization, to perform this task, you must have the following permission.

```
billing.accounts.create
```

### Organization

-An **Organization is the root node** of the Google Cloud hierarchy of resources.

-All Google Cloud resources that belong to an Organization are grouped under the Organization node, allowing you to define settings, permissions, and policies for all projects, folders, resources, and Cloud Billing accounts it parents.

-An **Organization is associated with exactly one Domain (established with either a Google Workspace or Cloud Identity account), and is created automatically when you set up your domain in Google Cloud.**

-Using an Organization, you can centrally manage your Google Cloud resources and your users' access to those resources.

This includes:

1-Proactive management: reorganize resources as needed (for example, restructuring or spinning up a new division may require new projects and folders).

2-Reactive management: an Organization resource provides a safety net to regain access to lost resources (for example, if one of your team members loses their access or leaves the company).

-The various roles and resources that are related to Google Cloud (including the organization, projects, folders, resources, and Cloud Billing accounts) are managed within the Google Cloud Console.

Check the reference:

### [Overview of Cloud Billing concepts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts#organization)

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to be able to create the billing account without associating it to an organization. Do you know if it's possible? The creation form has Organization as a required field, so it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: You required an organization check this tutorial from Google Cloud Tech https://youtu.be/NeRYUoR4u0s

Comment: Does this mean that if we are part of any gcp organisation, we'll no longer have the option to create a billing account for "No organisation"?